# Cross platform code in python

Tags: python

How can I write in python some windows code to execute only when I am running the script in widnows, if I should run it in linux, that part of the windows code should be ignored, something simillar to this, in C++:

```
#ifdef windows
  //code
#endif

#ifdef linux
//code
#endif
```

I tried something like this in python:

```
if os.name = 'nt':
   #code
```

But in linux it gives me an error(I am using STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW, witch gives error).

```
startupinfo = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= _subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW #error here
    startupinfo.wShowWindow = _subprocess.SW_HIDE # error here

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/astanciu/workspace/test/src/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    import _subprocess
ImportError: No module named _subprocess
```

Comment: Should that be `if os.name == 'nt':`?

Comment: How about using `sys.platform`?

Comment: sorry, i ment == there, wrote bad here

Comment: @ Sven Marnach: no module named _subprocess, but i dont gives me the error when importing, only when using it but the error is only an the STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW part.

Comment: @ Helper Method: still same errors

Comment: @vBx: Your error is unrelated to the code above.  Show the code that produces the error and the full error message (including tracback).

Comment: @ Sven Marnach: i changed the post

Comment: The traceback points to a line at module level containing an import. *Of course* that one is executed.

Comment: The error occurs in the line `import _subprocess`, not in the lines you marked.  Try commenting the latter out, and the error will persist.

Comment: yes, you are right still getting the error. Thats why i wanted that code to execute only in windows, so do I have other options ?

Comment: Move the import inside the if-statement, so it gets only executed on Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checks for the platform should be necessary at much fewer places in Python than in C.  If you really have to do it, the preferred way is to check [`sys.platform`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.platform) rather than `os.name`.

Comment: ive done this: if sys.platform == 'win32' but it is still the same, the windows code gets compiled

Answer (score 3):

You can have conditional code based on the value of [`os.name`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.name) using the correct comparison operator (`==`):

```
if os.name == 'nt':
   #code
```