# Cross-platform screenshot in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, cross-platform, screenshot

There are [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644908/take-screenshot-in-python-cross-platform) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653621/python-cross-platform-compatible-multi-screen-screenshot) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489552/cross-platform-code-in-python) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653621/python-cross-platform-compatible-multi-screen-screenshot) like this one, but none of them seem to be both cross-platform and specifically for Python 3, and I'm struggling to find a reliable solution.

How can I take a cross-platform screenshot in Python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current solution has been to use the `ImageGrab` function from the [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/) library, like so:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
image = ImageGrab.grab()
```

Comment: This appears to be macOS and Windows only. Is there something that works for Linux as well?

Comment: Sadly, this is the best I've found so far. If someone does come across one that works on Linux as well, that would be ideal. (I don't use Linux, so I wasn't aware that this didn't work on Linux; thanks for letting me know.)

Comment: Curently, it's cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use platform.system() to find the current OS, and then use a different solution depending on the operating system:

```
import platform
if platform.system()=="Windows":
    ...
elif platform.system()=="Darwin": #Mac
    ...
elif plarform.system()=="Linux":
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use PrtSc Library.

Command : pip3 install PrtSc

Code :

```
import PrtSc.PrtSc as Screen
screen=Screen.PrtSc(True,"file.png")
```

Comment: After downloading the source for this package, I noticed this is just a wrapper of pyscreenshot. pyscreenshot has become mostly obsolete after the Pillow module started supporting Linux as well (according to their own Github page).